# Проблемы с кодировкой ответа сервера в eclipse

Tags: java, кодировка, eclipse, сервлеты

Из java-сервлета посылаю на сторонний web-сервер GET запрос, получаю в ответ html код, запихиваю этот код в строку. Смотрю в строку -а русские буквы в ней в виде ромбиков с вопросиками. В самом html документе кодировка нигде не указана. Поэтому вручную перекодировываю строку в UTF-8. Не помогло.

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException  {
    String url = "http://meteonovosti.ru/index.php?index=8&value=26063";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    String answer = response.toString();
    System.out.println("Оригинальный ответ: "+answer);
     answer = new String(answer.getBytes(), "UTF-8" );
     System.out.println("После перекодирования: "+answer);
```

Оба вывода одинаковы (пропущены куски html кода):

Оригинальный ответ:  �����-��������� : ����� ������

После перекодирования:  �����-��������� : ����� ������

В настройках Эклипса везде указано использовать UTF-8. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы получить русские буквы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто текст приходит не в UTF-8. Вы создаете строку из байтового массива, байтовый массив ничего не знает о кодировке, это просто набор байт, чтобы сделать из него строку, нужно указать кодировку

```
answer = new String(answer.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Вы указали UTF-8, но исходный текст перед преобразованием в байтовый массив был представлен в другой кодировке. В какой?
Я прошел по вашей ссылке `http://meteonovosti.ru/index.php?index=8&value=26063`, открыл в браузере консоль разработчика, там во вкладке Network можно увидеть различные http-заголовки, один из них был

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=koi8-r
```

Значит ваш русский текст был представлен в кодировке koi8-r, следовательно строку вам нужно инициализировать так:

```
answer = new String(answer.getBytes(), "KOI8-R");
```

**UPD.**

Извиняюсь, поспешил, нужно указать кодировку для `InputStream`, а не для создаваемой строки.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "KOI8-R"));
```

**UPDUPD.**

Картинка, как это выглядит в браузере. Обычно нужно нажать F12, у вас откроется похожее полуокно, затем в адресной строке переходите на нужную вам страницу и на вкладке Network будут все http-запросы, обычно основной запрос находится вверху. Мой скришнот из Firefox, в Хроме всё выглядит похоже.

[image: вот]

Comment: К сожалению, теперь русские буквы выглядят вот так: "©╫О©╫О©╫О©╫".

Comment: @AlisaKorn, извиняюсь, дополнил ответ

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо большое! Правда, до сих пор не могу найти место, где была бы указана кодировка.

Comment: @AlisaKorn, приложил скриншот

Comment: Спасибо, нашла. Но появилась новая загадка: в Response Headers кодировка присылается "charset=windows-1251", как я вижу.

Comment: В Response Headers в вашей программе?

Comment: Нет, в браузере. Ссылка на скриншот: https://pp.userapi.com/c621515/v621515219/1b8ec/4C1-88MFfQ8.jpg

Comment: Возможно это от ОС зависит, я с линукса сижу, браузер при запросе посылает заголовки со сведениями об ОС, браузере и т.п., а сервер может в разной кодировке отдавать в зависимости от этого.

Comment: Собственно те же response headers вы можете посмотреть в своем приложении в режиме отладки. `((HttpURLConnection) connection).responses`

Comment: Довольно удивительно, что у меня выводятся русские буквы, если указать кодировку, которая используется у вас на линуксе. Большое спасибо еще раз.

Comment: В браузер может приходить ответ с кодировкой Cp1251, а в приложение - KOI8-R. Всё зависит от залоговков в Request.